# Растяжение сложного SVG на основе текста внутри него

Tags: javascript, css, html5, svg

Я создал в иллюстраторе SVG для расположения в качестве фона заголовков на веб-сайте, который я проектирую.

Я пытаюсь найти способ динамического изменения размера этого фонового SVG на основе текста внутри него.

Я уже использовал `lengthAdjust =" spacingAndGlyphs "`, однако  текст, который я ввел в него, становится довольно сжатым, если это более длинная строка, или довольно растянутым, если это более короткая строка текста.

Ниже мой код:

```html
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 23.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 431.31 58.47" style="enable-background:new 0 0 431.31 58.47;" xml:space="preserve">
      <style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#005FB3;}
 .st1{fill:none;}
 .st2{fill:#FFFFFF;}
 .st3{font-family:'neue-aachen-pro';font-weight:600;}
 .st4{font-size:40.8839px;}
 .st5{letter-spacing:-1;}
</style>
      <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M431.31,58.47L431.31,58.47c-143.6-9.99-287.71-9.99-431.31,0l0,0l19.76-17.44c10.02-7.32,10.02-16.27,0-23.59
  L0,0l0,0c143.6,9.99,287.71,9.99,431.31,0l0,0l-19.76,17.44c-10.02,7.32-10.02,16.27,0,23.59L431.31,58.47z"/>
        <rect x="27.04" y="6.33" class="st1" width="377.23" height="45.81"/>
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 40.04 40.407)" class="st2 st3 st4 st5 changeHead" textLength="351.23" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">This is the text that is getting squished.</text>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54575801/7394871

Answer (score 1):

Я сделал несколько изменений. Текст теперь центрирован вокруг центра элемента svg.

Я использую JavaScript для расчета длины текста и изменения размера текста, если он шире, чем 350 единиц.

Вы можете решить, что это максимальное значение 350 основывается на ширине прямоугольника `.st1`.

```js
// the initial text size
let fontSize = 40;
txt.setAttribute("style", `font-size:${fontSize}px`);
// get the length of the text
let textLength = txt.getComputedTextLength();

while(textLength > 350){// where 350 is the max width allowed
  fontSize --
  txt.setAttribute("style", `font-size:${fontSize}px`);
  textLength = txt.getComputedTextLength();
}
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
text{font-family:'neue-aachen-pro';fill:#FFFFFF;}
```

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 431.31 58.47" >
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#005FB3;}
 .st1{fill:none;} 
</style>
      <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M431.31,58.47L431.31,58.47c-143.6-9.99-287.71-9.99-431.31,0l0,0l19.76-17.44c10.02-7.32,10.02-16.27,0-23.59
  L0,0l0,0c143.6,9.99,287.71,9.99,431.31,0l0,0l-19.76,17.44c-10.02,7.32-10.02,16.27,0,23.59L431.31,58.47z"/>
        <rect x="27.04" y="6.33" class="st1" width="377.23" height="45.81"/>
        <text id="txt" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" x="215.655" y="29.235">This is the text, a very long text.</text>
      </g>
    </svg>
```